# migrating from Linux to Mac

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, mactex

For the longest time, I have written LaTeX documents on Unix or Linux. Due to several reasons, I'm actively planning to move this to Mac. I installed Mactex, Linux Libertine fonts, RomDev.tec and sanskrit 2003.ttf fonts.

My document uses Linux Libertine and several Indian language fonts, most important being Sanskrit 2003 (ttf).

To transliterate Sanskrit, I use Somadeva Vasudeva's RomDev scheme that uses a mapping file.

Here is a MWE that works on linux but not on the mac, I get 
fontspec error: "font-not-found"

The font "Linux Libertine" cannot be found

I believe I have all the required fonts in my mac. How do I verify if they are a) present and b) configured for `xelatex` to find them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % the multilingual support package
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} % this is mostly going to be English text, with
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit} % some Sanskrit embedded in it.

\usepackage{xltxtra} % standard for nearly all XeLaTeX documents
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, 
            ItalicFont={TeX Gyre Schola Italic},
            BoldItalicFont={TeX Gyre Pagella Bold Italic}]
            {Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=0.9]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Linux Libertine}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}
\newfontinstance
\sanskritunicode [Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Sanskrit 2003}

\newcommand\skt[2]{\textsanskrit{#1#2}}
\newcommand\sktuni{\skt\sanskritunicode}

\newfontfamily\sa{Sanskrit 2003:script=deva}% Write Devanagari natively 

\newenvironment{sanskrittext}%
  {\leftskip=1em \rightskip=1em }%
  {\ifhmode \par \fi}

\newcommand\sloka[1]{\begin{sanskrittext}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}{\large \skt
    {\normalsize \textit{#1}}\end{sanskrittext}\medskip}

    \setlength\heavyrulewidth{1.5pt}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\begin{document}

{\Large \sa ॐ }

Everything is rooted in time, kāla:\\
\sloka{
kālamūlamidaṃ sarvaṃ bhāvābhāvau sukhāsukhe
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to copy the fonts in the `/Library/Fonts` folder in order that XeTeX can find them by name. Notice that `xltxtra` is needed for a really small number of documents nowadays. Just load `fontspec` instead.

Comment: I copied the Libertine otf fonts to /Library/Fonts and replaced \usepackage{xltextra} with \usepackage{fontspec}. The error still remains.

Comment: Open the Font Book application and make sure it finds those fonts.

Comment: Did that. Now it stops at 
l.19 \newfontinstance
It appears it is having problem processing: 
\newfontinstance
\sanskritunicode [Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Sanskrit 2003}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. The problems that I were encountering were two fold. TeX Live 2018 is the primary culprit. I could not compile my document on a fresh install of TeX Live 2018 on a Linux VM. I installed TeX Live 2015 version to compile without error. Next I installed TeX Live 2015 in my MBP. For fonts, I copied the TeX Gyre fonts to a separate local folder as Mac cannot read texlive fonts (& reason being Finder is not good at navigating system directories in MBP). I did the same for Indic fonts. Added these to Fontbook and voila, my book compiled successfully.